# multi select width issue in html 5

Tags: jquery, html, css

I used multiselection box in my project and when I select the option in the multi select it does not fit the width of the box as shown below.

[Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siJWM.png)

I wanted text to be hovered in fully till the end of the box.

**HTML CODE:**

```
<select class="form-control ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" style="width: 40%;height: 170px;overflow: scroll;display: inline; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px" multiple="true" ng-model="mapping.postrules" ng-options="rule as rule.name  for rule in postRules |filter:rule.rule='PostRule' | orderBy:'name' track by rule.id"
tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false">
  <option value="1082" label="asdasdasdasdasdsa">asdasdasdasdasdsa</option>
  <option value="1057" label="ATest">ATest</option>
  <option value="1019" label="Averylongrulenamethatforcestheusertoscrolltotherightwhenviewinginthelistbox">Averylongrulenamethatforcestheusertoscrolltotherightwhenviewinginthelistbox</option>
  <option value="1165" label="BDG - EmplID 'Test123' Can See data">BDG - EmplID 'Test123' Can See data</option>
  <option value="1166" label="BDG - EmplID 'Test_Id' Can See data">BDG - EmplID 'Test_Id' Can See data</option>
  <option value="1173" label="BDG - ODM - Post Data - Engagement Rule">BDG - ODM - Post Data - Engagement Rule</option>
  <option value="1066" label="BDG - Sector - Sector Name">BDG - Sector - Sector Name</option>
  <option value="1176" label="BDG- ODM - Post Data - Client Rule">BDG- ODM - Post Data - Client Rule</option>
  <option value="1141" label="Filter Client Data">Filter Client Data</option>
  <option value="1140" label="Filter Engagement Data">Filter Engagement Data</option>
  <option value="1002" label="ND/rule/1113">ND/rule/1113</option>
  <option value="1169" label="Nirav/Custom/Sectorname">Nirav/Custom/Sectorname</option>
  <option value="1150" label="Nirav/ODM/Test">Nirav/ODM/Test</option>
  <option value="1060" label="Nirav_12/3.1">Nirav_12/3.1</option>
  <option value="1071" label="PwCNow_Opportunities_LKM">PwCNow_Opportunities_LKM</option>
  <option value="1047" label="Remove Field">Remove Field</option>
  <option value="1045" label="Remove First Row">Remove First Row</option>
  <option value="1072" label="RiverFilterOpportunities">RiverFilterOpportunities</option>
  <option value="1073" label="RiverFilterPipeline">RiverFilterPipeline</option>
  <option value="1094" label="rohanODMzyz">rohanODMzyz</option>
  <option value="1050" label="rohanTEST2">rohanTEST2</option>
  <option value="1174" label="rule1113">rule1113</option>
  <option value="1023" label="test1116 esttesttest  testtesttest testtesttest  testtesttest  testtesttesttesttesttest  testtesttest  testtesttesttesttesttest  testtesttest  testtesttesttesttesttest  testtesttest  testtesttest">test1116 esttesttest testtesttest testtesttest testtesttest testtesttesttesttesttest testtesttest testtesttesttesttesttest testtesttest testtesttesttesttesttest testtesttest testtesttest</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Post relevant part of your HTML and CSS (if you have any) in the question.

Comment: okay @Keammoort But I used native html with no css. Please check the updated question

Comment: It´s working on chrome and firefox (MAC). It fit all options. - http://jsfiddle.net/luispa/kd4kjdck/77/

Comment: This is minor, but just for future reference inline css is still css. You can't style anything in HTML without css in some form. I would consider placing all css in an actual style tag at the least as it does clean up your markup and makes it easier to make changes and fix issues in the future.

Comment: Setting the `width` on `option` to the maximum width of an option will do the trick something like `option {
  width: 1500px;
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of two things here:

1) Remove the `width` on the `<select>` tag and you should be all set.

```
          width:auto;
```

[JSFIDDLE FOR (1)](http://jsfiddle.net/jr6b7tag/1/)

2) If you have width constraint and need a 40% width on the select, the only other option left for you is to wrap the text for each of the options to the next line. add the following style to the `<select>` tag

```
         word-wrap:break-word;
```

[JSFIDDLE FOR (2)](http://jsfiddle.net/jr6b7tag/)